In Dynamics AX 2012 how to set default columns positions in form?
I have a Grid in my Form which has fields from two field groups and both field groups have fields from two separate tables.
I want to set default columns positions so that whenever any user opens form, fields should be in same sequence irrespective of personalization.
I think it needs to be set this with x++ code in Form init method, but I don't know how to do.
Thanks for help.
(I want to set sequence of column of each field in grid.)

Can you provide more information, screenshots, etc. to help us better answer the question? User personalization (usage data) is going to be something you'll need to decide on first. Do you want to disable personalization for this specific form?
